# Mongooseim match sub element value

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mongoose-im

I have a child element called Request inside my message element of xmpp packet. Therefore, my packet looks like the below:

```
<message to="b" from="a" type="chat"> 
    <request xmlns="urn:client:send-ack"></request> 
</message>
```

I want to match the value of xmlns attribute inside the request element. So I want to do something like

```
case xml:get_attr_s(<<"xmlns">>, xml_get_subtag(<<Request>>,Packet)) of
   "urn:client:send-receipts" ->
   %% Do something
   ok.
```

But, obviously this densest work. Whats the best way to do it ?

Comment: If you really want to use the `xml` module, then `xml:get_tag_attr(<<"xmlns">>, xml:get_subtag(El, <<"request">>))` is the way to go, but (arguably) `exml_query:path/2`, suggested by Piotr, has a more convenient interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy and fast way to get this attribute is `exml_query:path/2`. With it, your `case ... of` would be following:

```
case exml_query:path(Stanza, [{element, <<"request">>}, {attr, <<"xmlns">>}]) of
    <<"urn:client:send-receipts">> -> something;
    _ -> something_else
end
```

Comment: hey thanks it worked. But I have a small problem. I have two request tags in my packet. The one im looking for is the second one. But whenever I look for a match using exml_query:path it returns the first match. is there a way to loop through the packet or check the next match or something ?

Comment: In such case use `exml_query:paths/2` with the same arguments and it will return a list of results, in this case the list of `xmlns` values for both elements. Then you can use `lists:member/2` to check if the desired XMLNS is there.

Answer (score 1):

With latest ejabberd development version, you can do what you want with the following:

```
xml:get_subtags_with_xmlns(Parsed_xml, <<"request">>, <<"urn:client:send-ack">>).
```

It will match any number of subtags and return a list.

You need to build ejabberd from source or use the upcoming ejabberd 15.04 version, released before end of month.